# What should i put in x and y

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Previously i got average prices for gas like this:

```
1993 1.0711538461538466

1994 1.0778653846153845

1995 1.1577115384615386

1996 1.2445283018867925

1997 1.2442499999999999
```

I want to get a graph, so i tried this code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


with open('c:/Gasprices.txt', 'r') as file:
    td = dict()
    for line in file:
        year = line[6:10]
        price = float(line[11:])
        td.setdefault(year, []).append(price)
    for k, v in td.items():
        print(f'{k} {sum(v) / len(v):}')



x=[k], y=[sum(v) / len(v)]
plt.plot(x,y, 'o--')
plt.title('Average gas price per year in US')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('Avg.gas price per gallon[$]')
plt.grid()
plt.yticks(np.arange(1.0, 3.5, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

But i don't know what should i put in x and y.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and sample data and here is my assessment and answer:

First of all, just to answer your question in plain English, ' X ' is usually used for time and ' Y ' is usually for values that have changed over time although based on your code I think you know that, so ' Year ' would be ' X ' and ' Average Gas Price ' would be ' Y'.

Next I did some modifications to your code to make it work (which I will explain after):

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
x = list()
y = list()
with open('e:/Gasprices.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line_striped = line.strip()
        if line_striped == '':
            continue
        line_splitted = line_striped.split(' ')
        x.append(
            int(line_splitted[0])
        )
        y.append(
            float(line_splitted[1])
        )

plt.plot(x,y, 'o--')
plt.title('Average gas price per year in US')
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('Avg.gas price per gallon[$]')
plt.grid()
plt.yticks(np.arange(1.0, 3.5, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

So what's going on:

1. I created two empty lists before opening the file and subsequently iterating through its lines
2. Next inside the loop I made sure to skip over any empty line by using .strip() which removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string and then comparing the result to an empty string, if the resulting string is equal to an empty string, skip the line entirely.
3. And then and splitted the striped line by whitespace between characters which resulted in getting a list of two items, first element is the year and the second element is the average price.
4. Finally I added each value to its respective list, year to X and average price to Y.

I hope it helped.

P.S. My english is not very good so I hope my answer is somewhat readable.

Comment: Really thank you for your comment.  But my text file is seperated to date-year-price like (04-05-1993:1.068)   and i got average prices using the code  on upper side.  and i want to know if i can use the result for the average prices per year to x and y. My english is not really good too, so if you can't understand me please comment.

Comment: I don't quiet understand the logic behind average price formula that you used, so maybe if you could provide a sample of your file I could better help out. And I personally prefer the use of .split() function for each line, for example in (04-05-1993:1.068), I would've used one .split(':') to separate date and price and I would further separate date using .split('-') to get day, month, and year. If you could provide the .txt file I could take a look again.